# ASP.NET Core - How to Compress and Resize image and quality also

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

In my college ecommerce gallery project I want do  when the image is uploaded the size of the image automatically compressed like if the image size is 2mb after upload its gonna 600 kb or 400kb so how to do that..my code is below..

**ProductController.cs**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upsert(ProductVM productVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string webRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath; //getting image Path
                var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files; //Retrive all the files that are uploaded
                if(files.Count > 0) //that means file was uploaded
                {
                    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    var uploads = Path.Combine(webRootPath, @"images\products");
                    var extenstion = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);

                    if (productVM.Product.ImageUrl != null)
                    {
                        //this is an edit and we need to remove old image
                        var imagePath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, 
                        productVM.Product.ImageUrl.TrimStart('\\'));
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagePath))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(imagePath);
                        }
                    }
                    using (var filesStreams = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, fileName + 
                    extenstion), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        files[0].CopyTo(filesStreams);
                    }
                    productVM.Product.ImageUrl = @"\images\products\" + fileName + extenstion;
                }
                else
                {
                    //update when they do not change the image
                    if (productVM.Product.Id != 0)
                    {
                        Product objFromDb = await _unitOfWork.Product.GetAsync(productVM.Product.Id);
                        productVM.Product.ImageUrl = objFromDb.ImageUrl;
                    }
                }

                if (productVM.Product.Id == 0)
                {
                   await _unitOfWork.Product.AddAsync(productVM.Product);

                }
                else
                {
                    _unitOfWork.Product.Update(productVM.Product);
                }
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

            }
           ..
           ..
           ..
            return View(productVM);
        }
```

**Upsert.cshtml**

```
<section>
    <div class="container-lg pt-4">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row p-3 border">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                
                <div class="col-8 pt-4">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label asp-for="Product.Title"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input asp-for="Product.Title" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Product.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            Image
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input type="file" name="files" id="uploadBox" multiple class="form-control" 
                             />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-8 offset-4">
                            @if (Model.Product.Id != 0)
                            {
                                <partial name="_EditAndBackToListButton" model="Model.Product.Id" />
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Create</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <button asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success form-control">Back To List</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Is there any nuget package to compress the image size

Comment: [This nuget](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/LazZiya.ImageResize/v4.0/index.md) do resize, crop, adds text watermark, image watermark even on animated gifs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this demo, after testing, it can make 65KB image to 15KB image:

You just need to send source image location with the compress level 0~100, and where to send the

compressed image.

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string filename = @"C:\*****\Saved Pictures\dog.jpg"; //source image location
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(filename);   //image to bitmap                 
        var name = "result.jpg";  //your output image name
        Compress(img, @"C:\****\wwwroot\images\"+name, 0); //level 0~100, 0 is the worst resolution
        return View();
    }

    public static void Compress(Bitmap srcBitMap, string destFile, long level)
    {
        Stream s = new FileStream(destFile, FileMode.Create); //create FileStream,this will finally be used to create the new image 
        Compress(srcBitMap, s, level);  //main progress to compress image
        s.Close();
    }

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
    {
        int j;
        ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
        encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
        {
            if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                return encoders[j];
        }
        return null;
    }
    private static void Compress(Bitmap srcBitmap, Stream destStream, long level)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;
        Encoder myEncoder;
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;
        myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
        myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
        myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, level);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        srcBitmap.Save(destStream, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
    }
```

Result(after vs before):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes, you could use this: https://github.com/omuleanu/imager
so it would be something like this:

```
Image img = Imager.Resize(sourceImage, newWidth, maxHeight);
```

this is if you want to resize it on the server, after you uploaded it, but you could also resize it before the upload, as shown in this demo website:
https://prodinner.aspnetawesome.com/Meal

try to click edit on any item, after "change image"
for this cropper.js and dropzone.js are used.

https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/
https://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: don't need to change to width and height just if the image size is 2mb or 3mb after upload automatically gonna max 500kb or lower..no need to customized

Comment: The package I mentioned in my comment can reduce the quality without resize. Just use img.SaveAs(img-name, quality);

Comment: @SoumikMahajan then just have a look at the code and set the quality:
https://github.com/omuleanu/imager/blob/master/src/Imager/Imager.cs